# How to select specific radio button in a group of similar radio buttons in Selenium Web Driver?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to automate a booking process from an airline site.
In the second page of the booking process ('Select Flights'), there are multiple radio buttons which are very similar with other radio buttons available in the page. How can I select the radio button that I want to click?

I have already tried the xpath of the radio button but to no avail.
Here is the html code of the radio button:
[Screenshot from booking.airasia.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z91FM.png)

Please advise. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[First element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NikjY.jpg)
[image]

[Second Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U8cL.jpg)
[image]

Well its true that you are getting similar elements for that given xpath but you also have to go through their siblings/parents etc for different scenarios.
Here is the xpath I tried that identified the individual elements that you were looking for, are depicted above.

```
//div[@class='iradio_square-green']/input[@id='trip_0_date_0_flight_0_fare_0']/following-sibling::ins
```

For others radio buttons you just have to change the flight number.

Hope this helps...
:)

Comment: Oh! I missed that! Thanks BIJAY for giving me the exact xpath I needed. Worked like a charm!